# Calling function to show/hide imageviews from another class

Tags: java, android

In my MainActivity class I have this method:

MainActivity.java

```
public void ClearImageViews() {
  final ImageView image_a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_a);
  image_a.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 }
```

And in another file I have another class, which calls ClearImageViews method like this:

```
 MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
 mainActivity.ClearImageViews();
```

Im getting NullPointerExpection while running the code from findViewById function. When I comment out these lines:

```
 final ImageView image_a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_a);
 image_a.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

The code works well. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have called `setContentView()` for required xml layout in your `MainActivity`.

You need to call `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` in your `MainActivity` where your_layout is a xml file in which you have your ImageViews.

Or if you can't do it (because for example you need to use another layout in `MainActivity`), you have to inflate your ImageViews. Read about inflating views.

Answer (score 1):

By doing `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();` you are creating new activity instance..this is not the same activity that is running..
For the new one that you have created the `onCreate` is not called, so the content is not set for this the findViewById returns null...
You need to use a call back function to call `ClearImageViews()` in an appropriate way..

Another solution is to make the method `ClearImageViews()` static, and then call it using:

```
MainActivity.ClearImageViews()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you describe how to use callback function in proper way from another class?

Also, if I change ClearImageViews method to static method, I get error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity"

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `Activity` which has this `ImageView` as its Field as a `Context` to the another class.

Now use something like this...

```
class AnotherClass extends Activity{


 OriginalClass o;

 public AnotherClass(OriginalClass oo){

   this.o = oo;


}


final ImageView image_a = (ImageView)this.o.findViewById(R.id.image_a);

                // Use this.o.findViewById like above.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with moving this other class from top-level class to member class of MainActivity. With this arrangement I have access to findviewbyid from other class.